# Table in landscape with caption in normal orientation

Tags: tables, captions, lscape

Is there a way to have a table rotated using the `lscape` package and have the caption above or below it in normal (portrait) orientation?

Any help much appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
A & B & C & D & E \\
F & G & H & I & J \\
K & L & M & N & O \\
P & Q & R & S & T \\
U & V & W & X & YZ
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you please add a minimal example of your code.

Comment: Minimal example added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `minipage` and `\rotatebox`

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
A & B & C & D & E \\
F & G & H & I & J \\
K & L & M & N & O \\
P & Q & R & S & T \\
U & V & W & X & YZ
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
\rotatebox{270}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]