# Rotate only caption of a table

Tags: tables, landscape

Given this table

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
Example & A & B & C & D \\
A       & 1 &   & 1 &   \\
B       &   & 1 & 1 &   \\
C       & 1 &   &   & 1 \\
D       & 1 & 1 & 1 &  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

I would like to have the table in landscape orientation but the caption in the portrait one. Would it be possible even using other packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the table in landscape manually using `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package. Placing the caption outside of the rotatebox ensures that the caption is landscape (note that putting the caption inside of the box does not work, to rotate the caption as well you need the `landscape` environment).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
Example & A & B & C & D \\
A       & 1 &   & 1 &   \\
B       &   & 1 & 1 &   \\
C       & 1 &   &   & 1 \\
D       & 1 & 1 & 1 &  
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Non-rotated caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that in the example the tabular is centered using `\centering`. This is just to make the example a bit more compact, you probably don't need or want to center the table in your actual document.

For a related question with a solution that is a bit more complex but might suit your use case see [Table in landscape with caption in normal orientation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301438/table-in-landscape-with-caption-in-normal-orientation), where the table and caption is set in `landscape` and only the caption is rotated back with `rotatebox`.