# Sidewaystable with non-sideways caption

Tags: tables, formatting, rotating, sidewaystable

I am using the sidewaystable to display a rather long table sideways on a new page. The table is not so wide that it fills the long side of the paper but it has too many rows to fit the short side -- that is if the caption is added.

So I was wondering if there is a way to display the caption non-sideways and the table sideways? In this way the page would be completely filled.

I guess it is not 100% standard procedure but I do not think it would be a big problem.

Comment: Related questions/answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25387/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498598/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301438/134144

Comment: Probably you could transpose the table instead of rotating it?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429987/rotate-sideways-photo-with-caption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution with use `rotating` package and environment `\sideways`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering    % if you like to have table (vertically) centered
    \caption{My wide table}
\begin{sideways}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.91\textheight}{c X}
    \toprule
No. &   column header   \\
    \midrule
1   &   \lipsum[66]     \\
   \midrule
2   &   \lipsum[66]     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sideways}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]